# What's the advantage of specifying ActionName above an action method in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I my application code we have many instances of:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetQuestionHeaders")]
    public IList<QuestionHeader> GetQuestionHeaders(int id)
```

Where the ActionName is specified above the action.  I am not sure how it came about that these were added. Is there any advantage to having these?

Answer (score 3):

It's not useful in your example, but it's useful if you need similar methods on the same action, e.g. for POST/GET separation.

It's pretty rare though, because usually if you have GET and POST methods their signature differs, so this is an "emergency measure" more or less.

For example:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Submit(string someString)
{
   // Returning a View etc.
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Submit")]
// There is already a Submit(string) method, so this MUST be named differently.
public ActionResult SubmitPost(string someString)
{
   // Putting the string in the database etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly used in Routing configuration stuff.

Suppose you change your code like

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetQuestionHeaders")]
public IList<QuestionHeader> QuestionHeaders(int id)
```

Note : I've removed Get prefix from Action Method.
Routing will not have any effect on it since we've  not changed ActionName and Routing will match action with "GetQuestionHeaders" not QuestionHeaders.

QuestionHeaders : For internal usage

GetQuestionHeaders: For Routing engine usage.

By default it will same as specified Action name. You can change it by explicitly mentioning ActionName

Hope Helps.